# How to nest SELECT queries with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server

I have a nested SELECT query along with INNER JOIN. The idea is to fetch a Client's Username from a UserDetails table and TransactionId and Remarks from a LeaveDetails Table. I have a customer's UserId in both of these tables. I can fetch a Client's Username using Customer's UserId. The query goes like this:

```
SELECT 
dbo.UserDetails.[Username], dbo.LeaveDetails.[TransId], dbo.LeaveDetails.Remarks 
FROM dbo.UserDetails 
INNER JOIN 
dbo.LeaveDetails 
  ON dbo.LeaveDetails.UserId=@UID 
  AND dbo.LeaveDetails.[TransId] = @TransId
```

and in the above query, dbo.UserDetails.[Username] should be fetched as below.

```
SELECT 
dbo.UserDetails.[ClientUserId] from dbo.UserDetails 
WHERE UserId = @UID
```

And I merged the queries as below which throws an error.

```
SELECT 
dbo.UserDetails.[Username] 
WHERE 
UserId = (SELECT dbo.UserDetails.[ClientUserId] 
          from dbo.UserDetails 
          WHERE UserId = @UID), 
dbo.LeaveDetails.[TransId], dbo.LeaveDetails.Remarks 
FROM dbo.UserDetails 
INNER JOIN dbo.LeaveDetails 
  ON dbo.LeaveDetails.UserId=@UID 
  AND dbo.LeaveDetails.[TransId] = @TransId
```

Please share your opinion to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: mysql or sql-server?  There is a difference!

Comment: Which table is `UserId` in?

Comment: Seems to me your "ON Critera" should be in a where clause and the Foreign key relationship between user details and LeaveDetails should be used.  You're not telling the system how to JOIN the tables together.  Subquery doesn't look like it's needed at all.  Provide some sample data and expected results and I'm sure we can help.

Comment: @Jones, can you explain exactly what you are trying to do?  We think that you may be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF, Am using sql-server.

Comment: @Douglas Brabin, UserID mentioned was the CustUserId. I updated the query now. Sorry for the confusion.

I am trying to fetch Client's Username using nested SELECT queries. 
Client's Username can only be fetched with Client's User ID.
The customer (who logs in) will have Client's User ID. 

The nested SELECT is to fetch the Client's User ID by passing Customer's UserID. Customer's UserID is available as he/she logs in.

Once I have Client's UserID, I can populate the Username.

Comment: What is the relationship between `LeaveDetails` and `UserDetails`?  Which column(s) do they have in common?

Comment: This would be solved by now if we have sample data from both tables and an expected result using the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be a simple `join` with a `where` clause like this:

```
SELECT ud.Username
    ,ld.[TransId]
    ,ld.Remarks
FROM dbo.UserDetails ud
INNER JOIN dbo.LeaveDetails ld ON ld.UserId = ud.UserId
WHERE ud.ClientUserId IN (
        SELECT ud1.ClientUserId
        FROM dbo.UserDetails ud1
        WHERE ud1.UserId = @UID
        )
    AND ld.[TransId] = @TransId;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because presumably you can't join the two tables on `UserId`.  Since the `WHERE` clause includes only `UserId` (no table specified), it is assumed that it only exists in one table.  Otherwise it would be ambiguous and SQL Server would throw an error.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Thanks for the heads up on that ambigous column! Nice catch! I believe OP specifically mentions `I have a customer's UserId in both of these tables`.

Comment: I had put the nested SELECT at the wrong place. Thank you all for your inputs.

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working for you. I figured that you might have something mixed up in the nested query. :o)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could simply this greatly if a Relationship actually exists between LeaveDetails and userDetails.

```
SELECT UD.[Username], LD.[TransId], LD.Remarks 
FROM dbo.UserDetails  UD
INNER JOIN dbo.LeaveDetails LD
 ON UD.PKField = LD.FKField  <-- Change this to be your actual relationship
--Maybe ON UD.ClientUserID = LD.ClientUserID --Instead of above
WHERE LD.ClientUserId=@UID 
  AND LD.[TransId] = @TransId
```

Comment: Good point about the `JOIN` condition.  Looking at it, it makes no sense. I think this may be a classic case of the OP asking the wrong question.

Comment: Thanks, always have to look for that possibility in questions; especially frequent in OPs with low rep.  Not a slam against low rep everyone has to learn and happy to help; just usually trends that way.